# bs-select loading previous data - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-strap

I am using `AngularStrap` for selecting options and facing some issue in it.
Scenario:
For user A. cart items is zero.
For user B. cart items is 1.
Initially on loading select for user A, options in select will be empty but after loading options of user B (i.e. 1 item) and on reloading user A select, It is getting user B's cart item in options.
Here is code:

```
<select id="cartSelect" ng-model="user.cartId" ng-options="c.id as c.name for c in cartItems" bs-select class="select"></select>
```

**What I Tried**:
I tried resetting cartItems to empty array before loading of a cart.

```
$scope.cartItems = [];
```

I checked cartItems in console and it was showing 0.
But It was still loading options field with other user's cart items.
On using select instead of bs-select, It works fine.

Is there anyway I can reset select or fix this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please provide with more details, like jsFiddle.
I can suggest two possible solutions.

- Try to add $scope.$apply() after you set the array. Possible you modified the value outside angular life circle and angular is not knowing the modification. So just use apply to let angular know it.
- You are not modifying anything under $scope, any model should be under $scope. In your case you use`var cartItems = [];`The right way is to define`$scope.cartItems` and use it.

And they might not work, and you should always post with more details like your entire controller codes or related codes.

Comment: I am setting cartItems in scope, I missed that in question, Will try using $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
Problem was that `select` was unaware of changes made so I had to manually refresh select `ng-options`.  i.e.
I had to add

```
$('#cartSelect').selectpicker('refresh');
```

whereever model(cartItems) was changing in controller,

More details provided in attached Link: [Handle changes to option elements](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/pull/263)